# intercept the object from click as2

Tags: for-loop, actionscript, onclick, actionscript-2, movieclip

in ActionScript2 there is a way to intercept the click on a movieClip?

I'll explain; I've this code:

```
planGroup.createEmptyMovieClip("textObject", 90);

if (textArray != "")
{
    for (tn = 0; tn < textArray.length; tn++)
    {
        textFormat = new TextFormat();
        textFormat.size = 100 * 0.35;

        var lbl = planGroup.textObject.createTextField("My_Instance_Name", tn,xt - minPlanX, yt - minPlanY,150,90);
        lbl.text = textArray[tn].attributes.text;

        xt = textArray[tn].attributes.x * multFactor;
        yt = -textArray[tn].attributes.y * multFactor;

        planGroup.textObject.createEmptyMovieClip("invis", getNextHighestDepth());
        with (planGroup.textObject.invis) {
          beginFill(0x22ffff, 50);
          moveTo(xt - minPlanX, yt - minPlanY);
          lineTo(xt - minPlanX + 150, yt - minPlanY);
          lineTo(xt - minPlanX + 150, yt - minPlanY + 90);
          lineTo(xt - minPlanX, yt - minPlanY + 90);
          lineTo(xt - minPlanX, yt - minPlanY);
          endFill();
        }
        planGroup.textObject.onRelease = function() {
          trace("click");
        }
```

that is I want to make the text clickable..and with this code it is, but i want the onRelease() makes different things on different text..so, how can I understand where the click come from?

Furthermore i noticed that the shape is drawn only on the last item of the 'for'.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like you are overwriting the same `textObject` on every `tn` value. Did you try something like `textObject[tn]`?

Comment: hi @RST thank you for answering..I tought this method was too complicated to obtain what I want, so I used invisible buttons rather than invisible movie clip below the textField! cheers